# Can one dynamically add sections to a matlab publish script?

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab script, where I would like to dynamically create sections in my matlab publish.

At present, the only way I know to create a section break, is to put code like this in my script:

```
%% This is a section break
```

I'd like to run publish on my script, and have the section breaks get added as part of the publish.  For instance.  Say I had the following script:

```
breaks(1).name = 'This is section break 1.';
breaks(2).name = 'This is section break 2.';

for ix = 1 : numel(breaks)
   functionThatInsertsSectionBreakTitle(breaks(ix).name);
   fprintf('Some random processing associated with break %d.\n', ix);
end
```

I would like to call publish on that script, and end up with a document that looks something like:

> **This is section break 1.**
>
> Some random processing associated with break 1.
>
> **This is section break 2.**
>
> Some random processing associated with break 2.

Obviously I could do this by writing a script that writes a script that then gets executed by publish.  I was hoping for something a bit more direct.  Am aware of the report generation toolbox, which I would hope would cleanly handle this type of scenario.  Alternatively, if the new (as of R2016a) [Live Script](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-live-script.html) handles this use case, that's a fine answer as well.

Comment: So you want to programmatically create the `.m` file?

Comment: @Suever: that would at least be a solution to the stated problem. I am not too sure, but the publishing functionality is quite limited. Mathwork's "Report Generation" (another toolbox) alternatively allows for a more detailed configuration.

Comment: @Suever, not my post. :D

Comment: @Suever No, I do not want to programmatically create the .m file.  I know how to do that, it's not hard, but ugly.

Comment: Know of the existence of report generation toolbox, but am getting a bit frustrated at the endless nickel and diming of mathworks, and was hoping to avoid adding yet another toolbox to my list of required matlab products.

Comment: @John Can you show us what you actually want. As you're written it it's not clear what you expect

Comment: As far as I know, `publish` works by parsing the document literally, noting special comments starting with `%%`, and then executing the file.  There's no programmatic way to my mind to add sections in that scenario.  This seems to contrast with MATLAB Report Generator that builds a structured document via a DOM object.  If you want to use `publish`, I think writing a script to write a script is the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to address this problem is by displaying html code in the command output (documented [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btga6k2-1)).

In your example, the code would look like this:

```
breaks(1).name = 'This is section break 1.';
breaks(2).name = 'This is section break 2.';

for ix = 1 : numel(breaks)
    disp(['<html><h2>' breaks(ix).name '</h2></html>']);
    fprintf('Some random processing associated with break %d.\n', ix);
end
```

This is incredibly useful when you want to get results to be displayed with a custom layout, such as a table. And it avoids the need of having a Matlab Report Generator license...

Comment: Wow!  So obvious in hind sight.  Thanks!