# MATLAB string variables in comment

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to Publish a document that has a combination of figures and text. I want to add headings using the [text formatting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btfv_lg-1) which seems to treat code comments as headers, etc. The problem is that since my document is dynamically generated, there are `n` headings with different names.

Here's a simple example

```
for i = 1:3
    %% This is heading i
    % This is content i
end
```

Which I would expect to produce

## This is heading 1

This is content 1

## This is heading 2

This is content 2

## This is heading 3

This is content 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one dynamically add sections to a matlab publish script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792308/can-one-dynamically-add-sections-to-a-matlab-publish-script)